# Why would a function app regularly be down and how can this be prevented?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

We have built some function apps as part of a product and deployed them to a number of customers. Each customer has their own copy on their own Azure subscription. The function apps are Http Trigger which, for the most part, receive webhook data, do some lookup and manipulation of the data and add the result to the database. There are also some that lookup the data and return to the app. They could be taking a while to return data.

We have seen very infrequently that the function apps are not reachable. i.e. if we call http://.azurewebsites.net we get a 503 error. This is usually remedied by restarting them from within the Azure console.

However there is one customer whose apps are regularly failing.

Would this error be because of the code within the function app or is there a problem with the infrastructure? Is there a way of determining this?

Comment: Can you give any details on what your Azure Functions do? E.g. are they HttpTrigger endpoints, and are they taking too long to return data?

Comment: @AndrewB I have edited the question to include some more details about the function apps.

Comment: There's a limit to how long an `HttpTrigger` function is allowed to take to execute. I wonder if the Azure infrastructure is terminating your app whenever one of the calls takes a long time to run? If you're doing long-running work in an HttpTrigger, consider instead posting the data into a Queue and processing it there. If you expand your question a bit, with some sample code, maybe we can help show how to restructure it for using Azure Queues or similar.

Comment: I am already using Azure queues. The only alternative is to split up the function app into smaller parts and use queues.

However, should the fact that a function takes a long time, grind the whole function app "site" to a halt preventing a call to it?

Comment: It's not that the HttpTrigger itself is causing the app to grind to a halt. Rather, it's that the Azure infrastructure determines it's likely a fault in your app because it's taking so long to return an HTTP response, and terminates it. Also it's likely that any clients calling your endpoint will also close the connection if it's taking that long; so long-running processing in an HTTP endpoint is generally to be avoided regardless of tech stack.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1341696/cant-change-timeout-for-httpclient-when-running-az

Comment: Thanks for your input so far and I understand what you are saying. However the majority of calls to this are from webhooks i.e. I don't believe that there is a client at the other end waiting for a response. Is there a way of seeing within Azure when these shutdowns happen? Also if the function is being shut down, shouldn't the next one be accepted? At the moment if you attempt to ping the function app site you get a 503 back and have to restart the function app for it to work again.

Comment: Yes, I see your point now actually. Odd that it doesn't recover. I still think it's the long running endpoints, but perhaps a different side effect. Socket exhaustion, because each call is hanging on to a socket for several minutes?